# How to use sweetalert in a .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sweetalert

So I have a .js file, and I'm trying to throw a message to the user using sweetalert. Moreover, I also want to load .js and .css files of sweetalert, dynamically inside the .js file.

```
 // Load script
 var filerefjs = document.createElement('script');
 filerefjs.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
 filerefjs.setAttribute("src", "../../rotateScreen/dist/sweetalert.min.js");

 // Load CSS file
 var filerefcss = document.createElement("link");
 filerefcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
 filerefcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
 filerefcss.setAttribute("href", "../../rotateScreen/dist/sweetalert.css");

  if (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){ 

      window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('b6').onclick = function(){
           swal({title: "",   text: "Message", 
                imageUrl: "../../rotateScreen/example/images/rotate.png", confirmButtonText: "OK"});
        };
      } 

   } // if
```

I don't get any errors, but the alert-box does not appear on the screen .

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct (According to there website). Double check that you're actually linking the sweetalert.js file correctly. Also have a look at the console in CHROMES developer tools and make sure there are no errors, it will display if there are any unlinked files or missing files.

I tested this bit of code and it works fine inside a .js file

```
sweetAlert('error', "Enter A valid email please", 'error');
```